# Replace values in Arlgist

Tags: c#

I have an arglist and I want to replace the values of some of the indexes.

```
foreach (var item in arg.ArgListHashTable.Values)
{
    if (item != null)
    {   
        var list = item.ToString().Replace(rtfHead, "")
                                  .Replace(rtfClauseHead, "")
                                  .Replace(rtfClauseFoot, "")
                                  .Replace(rtfFoot, "")
                                  .Replace(tab, ".\tab ")
                                  .Replace(tab, "\tab ");
    }
}
```

After replacing the string value in list variable how to put it back to the arglist variable arg.

Comment: Can you please provide the class structure of item and What .ToString() on item does.

Comment: I wonder why checking `if (item != null)`? If there's no data in `.Values`, the loop body won't even be executed.